# How to create custom 404 and 500 page handler with Play 2.0(java)?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Code

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {      
    @Override
    public Result onHandlerNotFound(String s) {
        return notFound(views.html.error.render());
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You class is not loaded by Play as a [Global object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaGlobal). Either rename the `error` class to `Global` and put it in in your `app` folder (at the root).

Either, modify your `application.conf` file in order to update the path to the Global object:

```
...
# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
global=your.package.to.error
...
```

Comment: For the compilation error, please update your question with the new code. For the example, if your class is called `error`, and if it is located in the package `foo.bar`, then, you should use `global=foo.bar.error`.

Comment: You don't need to add a new route for the 404. Play! will handle it for you.